# FSharp.Data.Toolbox.Twitter truncates Text to 140 characters

Tags: twitter, f#, f#-data

F#'s type provider for Twitter doesn't seem to have been updated to account for the larger 280 character limit. Is anyone aware of a work-around or is this no longer usable?